# Problem setting up VS2019 Community for unit testing a dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll

I am using vs 2019 Community and have created a Class Library (.NET Framework) project named TestDLL.

The project contains a single file "TestDLL.cs" which has TestDLL as a namespace, a public class named MyDll and a single method

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace TestDLL 
{ 
    public class MyDLL 
    { 
        static bool Opposite(bool input) 
        { 
            return !input; 
        } 
    }
}
```

To the solution I added Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) named UnitTest, added TinyLib_dll.dll as a reference, and created the very simple test.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            bool start = true;
            bool result = MyDLL.Opposite(start);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(start, result, "MyDll.Opposite failed");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test, the dll file compiles successfully, but the UnitTest fails with "Error  CS0103  The name 'MyDLL' does not exist in the current context  UnitTest".

It appears that although I have referenced the dll as a reference it is not being loaded into the test project.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a `TestDLL` namespace in the test in order for the test to recognize the subject class

either add a using namespace

```
using TestDLL;

//...
```

or use the full name of the type

```
//...

bool result = TestDLL.MyDLL.Opposite(start);

//...
```

Comment: Good suggestions and I did forget to add the using TestDLL to my simple example, but adding this just moves the error to the using statement.  Also, using bool result = TestDLL.MyDLL.Opposite(start); moves the error indicator to the TestDLL. It appears that the test project can't see the project being tested at all.

Comment: @John update your post to show the all of the actual class to be tested, including namespaces as they appear in the file.

Comment: I hope this helps.

Comment: I was unsuccessful in updating the original post, but here is the file to be tested.//Class1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestDLL
{
    public class MyDLL
    {
        static bool Opposite(bool input)
        {
            return !input;
        }

    }
}

Comment: @John in that last code snippet you posted the static method is not public.

Answer (score 0):

In my haste to resolve my problem i submitted code samples with simple compilation errors.  Correcting these errors resolved my stated problem.  However I now have a new issue with the same project, but for clarity I will submit a new question.  I offer thanks to Nkosi for his assistance.